# Creating a dataframe from an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have made a data frame from an excel file using python:

```
  df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path_from_db, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)
```

What i am now trying to do is to set a new dataframe as the last 12 columns of my the sheet 1 in the excel file.

I know that the using openpyxl i can access the the sheet via:

```
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
```

and i know i can access the last column via:

```
ws.max_column
```

I guess I want to access the last column by `ws.max_column` and then make the proceeding 11 columns to that my dataframe. I know what i should do but I have no idea how to do it in code.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying explicitly on `openpyxl`, you can select the last 12 columns directly in `pandas` using `iloc` on the dataframe you've already loaded:

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, -12:]
```

The `:` says "take all rows" and the `-12:` says "take all columns starting at the 12-th-from-last"

Comment: works perfectly, thank you  i really appreciate it